# Possible scripting error on all main SE front pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

In Firefox and IE, I'm seeing this bug on all main SE front pages:

[image: scripting error]

It's showing `docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);` on the top of the front page.

Comment: I thought it's only for the Devops site!  Also, had the screenshot ready for a Meta post  :D

Comment: Same on The Workplace.

Comment: It doesn't appear on some subpages (e.g. `/questions/`) but I'm encountering it on the main page of all sites... but not meta :)

Comment: Yeah, copy/paste fail when refactoring some view logic, and that only shows up some of the time :/ Pushing a fix in a moment.

Comment: Rolled back to the previous build, then double, triple and quadruple checking the view. Still looking at what happened, but basically, it's a banner that isn't always shown, so I didn't see it and it doesn't always show for everyone. Sorry about that!

Comment: Properly fixed it and rolled out the latest build again. [Hero working as expected again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37Tl17aDZC4)

Comment: @Michael buy a beer to all of us and you shall be forgiven. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard In the spirit of "Give a man a fish", I have something even better than giving a beer: An entire site dedicated to making your own beer! http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ShadowWizard or post an appropriate question at DevOps.SE about best practices to prevent such "production problems" (hint 1: "four eyes" hint 2: "representative test data" ... hint 1234: "the best test is in production, and just rollback if it doesn't seem to work as intended").

Comment: @Pierre heh, sure'y Michael is well aware of all these. This just proves we are all humans. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard sure we're all humans, but it also proofs that SE has some serious DevOps challenges (our should I say "business opportunities"). My favorite "challenge" to SE, whenever these kinds of oeps-cases show up: "Which QA-environment does SE have available to have their end-users QA-review the suggested change, prior to moving it to production"? ... And if there is such environment, "where are the proofs of your test-results"?

Comment: @Pierre big changes go through this very site first, and/or Meta Stack Overflow which is even bigger in scale and users. That's their test ground. As for this specific glitch, it was just a small mistake, and all in all no harm done. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Yeah, copy/paste fail when refactoring some view logic, and that only shows up some of the time :/ Pushing a fix in a moment.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953837_293434)

> [Rolled back to the previous build, then double, triple and quadruple checking the view. Still looking at what happened, but basically, it's a banner that isn't always shown, so I didn't see it and it doesn't always show for everyone. Sorry about that!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953840_293434)
>    – Michael Stum♦

So everything is fixed now. Yay! :P

Comment: Stealing repz from dev... tsk tsk.

Comment: Yep, I'm evil that way...

Comment: Well, devs should know better than to write answers in comments.